# Prevent user from creating self intersected polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, digitizing

i'm working on a project in QGIS 3.4.1 Madeira. I want to prevent users from creating polygons with errors (like self intersection). When I digitize a polygon in QGIS i get a mark where the polygon self-intersects (see image), but I can continue and save my polygon without any further warning. Is there an option to prevent that and not ignore the topological error so that the user can redo his digitalization (e.g. pop up)?

[image: self intersect]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Layer Properties, Digitizing tab, tick on *Is Valid* Geometry check.

https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#digitizing-properties